# python function calling with dict - calling a function which has parameters but not listing the parameter explicitly

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a script used to count the number of words in a text file called alice. Practicing from https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files I understand how it all works with one exception shown here:

```
def get_count(word_count_tuple):
  return word_count_tuple[1]
```

My understanding is this function is called when items are sorted and they are sorted by the value of the 'get_count'
'get_count' has the parameter 'word_count_tuple' which is not used/assigned at any stage, and 'word_count_tuple[1](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files)' is returned.
Can someone explain what is happening here, and how it works, because i thought functions have to have a parameter value passed, or to have a default one, which this does not. Or is it assigned in some manner with the key and i am missing it?

this is the full code :

```
def word_count_dict(filename):
  word_count = {}
  input_file = open(filename, "r")
  for line in input_file:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
      word = word.lower()
      if not word in word_count:
        word_count[word] = 1
      else:
        word_count[word] += 1
  input_file.close()
  return(word_count)

def get_count(word_count_tuple):
  return word_count_tuple[1]

def print_top(filename):
  word_count = word_count_dict(filename)
  items = sorted(word_count.items(), key = get_count, reverse = True)
  for item in items[:20]:
    print (item[0], item[1])

def main():
  filename = "alice.txt"
  print_top(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are partially correct, you need to pass a parameter. 
Look at this line

```
items = sorted(word_count.items(), key=get_count, reverse=True)
```

In this line you are returning a sorted (in non-increasing order) copy of `word_count` based on the count and not the word.

Have a look at `key`. It takes a function that returns a value by which we need to sort every element in the list we are sorting.

Meaning if every element in `word_count.items()` was `x`, then we would have to sort the list using `x[1]` which is the value and `x[0]` is the key.

`key` takes a function or a lambda object as its value which is "applied" over every item in the list to be sorted.

Another way of doing the same functionality would be

```
items = sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])
```

This sorts the items by the negative of the value, so that we get the sorted list in reverse!

Comment: The key goes through every 'thing' in the word_count dict. word_count has two assigned values, the word x[0] and the value/occurance of the word x[1]. when it is sorted, is loops through everything sorted by the key(ie the word), but as it is split out into items (word x[0], value x[1]) the return of word_count_tuple[1] returns the count? Is that correct? If so i understand

Comment: quick follwo up question, why can't you just do key = word_count[1]? i tried and it came up with an error, but what is the reasoning for it? I dont understand

Comment: word_count being a dictionary that you are sorting, word_count[1] only makes sense to return a value corresponding to the key 1, which doesn't make sense right?

Comment: what `key` does is -> for every `x` in `container`, sort `x` by `key(x)`

Comment: Is that not what is done with the function though? Is it not the same end result?

Comment: by doing this `key = word_count[1]`, you will get an error if 1 is not a key in `word_count`, and even if it is `key` would be some constant that has nothing to do with sorting two elements in `word_count.items()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180610/discussion-between-atul-shanbhag-and-tejkaran-samra).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a little confusing when you first look at it.

`get_count` is being called by the `sorted()` function and being passed items one-by-on from `word_count.items()`.

If your word count dictionary looks like this:

```
{'mark': 2, 'the': 5, 'hotdog': 1}
```

Then `items()` will be an iterator with values like:

```
[('mark', 2), ('the', 5), ('hotdog', 1)]
```

So sorted takes each one of these and passes it to `get_count` like `get_count(('mark', 2))`, `get_count` then returns the `2` which `sorted` uses as the key for sorting.